# Explicit solution for the expectation of inverse of the exponential of normal random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be some constants, and let $N$ be a random variable with standard normal distribution.

Question: is there an explicit solution to
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{A+B e^{C N}}\right]?$$

If $A=0$, then the answer is $\frac{e^{\frac{C^2}{2}}}{B}$ which follows from the moment generating function. But if $A\neq 0$, using the density function of $N$,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{A+B e^{C N}}\right]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{A+B e^{C x}}\cdot \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}dx$$
would lead nowhere.

Comment: Maybe can refer to this
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331751/reciprocal-of-shifted-lognormal-random-variable
which direct to the Johnson's SB Distribution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_SU-distribution#Johnson's_SB-distribution

Comment: Much appreciated, the random variable $\frac{1}{A+B e^{CN}}$ follows logit normal distribution and its mean does not have an analytical solution.

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth, when $A=B$, you have a closed form solution. Consider $A=B=1$ to keep it simple:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial C} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})}{1+\exp(Cx)}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{-x\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})e^{Cx}}{(1+\exp(Cx))^2}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{-x\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})}{\big(e^{-Cx/2}+e^{Cx/2}\big)^2}dx = 0
\end{align*}
with the last equality due to the integrand being an odd (absolutely integrable) function.

When $C$ goes to $-\infty$, you find (with the dominated convergence theorem) that the common value is $\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$. Hence: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})}{1+\exp(Cx)}dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Comment: This is exactly correct, but I was using a different technique, since $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) dx =\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2} dx $.

Comment: You are exactly right and your answer's the shortest one as well (it would benefit from making explicit that the first equality comes from a change of variable $y=-x$ and then taking the average of the two, equal, integrals)

Answer (score 0):

You could expand the reciprocated expression as a geometric series  $ \frac{ 1}{ 1+ m e^x}=  \sum_k (-1)^k m^k e^{kx}$
and integrate termwise.

Comment: By this approach, we have $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{1+Ae^{Bx}}]=1+\sum_{i\geq 1}(-1)^iA^i e^{B^2i^2/2}$ which still doesn't have a closed form.

Comment: Worse, this series diverges!

Answer (score 0):

For $A=B \ne 0$: There is a solution, based on symmetry.

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{A+A e^{C x}}\cdot \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}dx = \frac1{2A} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{C x}}+ \frac{1}{1+e^{-C x}} \right)\cdot \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}dx = \frac1{2A} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}dx = \frac1{2A} $$

For $A \ne B$, I guess there is no closed-form solution, since my Mathematica just gave up on the integral. But of course, you can try some numerical integration, if you are facing a real-world problem.

Comment: The first equality does not hold because $\frac{1}{1+e^{Cx}}\neq \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1+e^{Cx}}+\frac{1}{1+e^{-Cx}})=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Amira It holds, because substituting $x$ to $-x$ does not change the value of integral.